# git replace file content in history

Tags: git, git-filter-repo

I would like to replace the content of a file in all branches with the current visible version of that file.
I have been trying  something like this, but it does not work:

```bash
FILE_PATH="$1"

cp "$FILE_PATH" "/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history"

git filter-repo --path "$FILE_PATH" --force --blob-callback "
  if filepath == b'$FILE_PATH':
    with open('/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history', 'rb') as f:
      blob.data = f.read()
"

rm "/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history"
```

I wondering, but I could not find any ready to use solution. Probably you have a better idea.

I want to remove encrypted files which could contain passwords etc, which should not be there. So the files are binary and should be replaced complete.

Comment: "*it does not work*" is uninformative. Please add error message(s) / unexpected outcome / (missing) expected outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing entire file content seems to be the area where `git filter-repo` has problems. Blob callback doesn't know filename, `--replace-text` can only replace line by line AFAIU.

I can solve your task with `git filter-branch`. Yes, I know it's outdated and not recommended. It works on one branch at a time. I use `--tree-filter` which is extra slow because it checks out every commit, updates it and commits it back. But still here is the working solution:

```bash
FILE_PATH="$1"

cp "$FILE_PATH" "/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history"

FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch --tree-filter "
    cp '/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history' '$FILE_PATH'
" HEAD

rm "/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history"
```

After that run `git log -- "$FILE_PATH"` — the log should contain only one commit, the initial commit.

*Upd*. Process all branches and copy tags:

```bash
FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 git filter-branch --tree-filter "
    cp '/tmp/file_to_replace_in_git_history' '$FILE_PATH'
" --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Comment: `git filter-branch … -- --all` rewrites all commits in all branches at once. You might want to supply `--tag-name-filter cat` too, to rewrite/update tags to point to the rewritten commits.

Answer (score 1):

#### How to prevent it from happening?

- First let's start with how to prevent it next time.
- You should user smudge/clean filters to scan and filter your sensitive information.
- The smudge/clean are filters which are runs whenever you commit file (clean) and checkout file to a working directory (smudge).

---

#### ***`Smudge / clean`***

Read all about it and to set it up here:
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes

> It turns out that you can write your own filters for doing substitutions in files on **commit/checkout**.
>
> These are called `clean` and `smudge` filters.
>
> In the `.gitattributes` file, you can set a filter for particular paths and then set up scripts that will process files just before they’re checked out (“smudge”) and just before they’re staged (“clean”).
>
> These filters can be set to do all sorts of fun things.

[image]

---

### ***`How to remove sensitive data from the repository`***

- You can use `git filter-branch` or BFG.

#### BFG

https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/

#### `BFG Repo-Cleaner`

[image]

- An alternative to git-filter-branch.
- The BFG is a simpler, faster alternative to git-filter-branch for cleansing **bad data** out of your Git repository history:

#### Examples (from the official site)

Replace all passwords listed in a file (prefix lines 'regex:' or 'glob:' if required) with ***REMOVED*** wherever they occur in your repository :

```bash
$ bfg --replace-text passwords.txt  my-repo.git
```

---

#### Smudge/Clean demo

```bash
# Source: https://github.com/nirgeier/git-scripts/blob/master/smudge/remove-localhost/remove-localhost.sh

#!/bin/bash

### Define the desired filters.
### For the simplicity of the demo we use it inline
### In real life it can be any path to actual script

### The ip which we wish to use
### In real life it can be password, ip , token or any other value
DB_IP_LOCAL=127.0.0.1
DB_IP_PROD=10.10.10.10

# Generate the .env file
echo -e "${Cyan}* Initializing\t .env file"
cat << EOF >> .env
## Database
##  * Local:      <Any Value>
##  * Production: 10.10.10.10
database.ip=0.0.0.0

## Feature1
feature1.env=DEV
feature1.key=f1-key
feature1.name=feature1
EOF

### Init the empty repository
echo -e "* Initializing demo repository"

## Init git repo
git init --quiet

### MacOS users should use gsed instead of sed

# Clean is applied when we add file to stage
echo -e "* Define clean filter"
git config --local filter.cleanLocalhost.clean  "gsed -e 's/database.ip=.*/database.ip=${DB_IP_PROD}/g'"

# Smudge is applied when we checkout file
echo -e "* Define smudge filter"
git config --local filter.cleanLocalhost.smudge "gsed -e 's/database.ip=*/database.ip=${DB_IP_LOCAL}/g'"

###  Define the filters 
echo -e "* Adding filters (smudge-clean) to demo repository"
echo '.env text eol=lf filter=cleanLocalhost' > .gitattributes

### Commit the file again after we set up the filter
echo -e "* Adding second commit"
echo 'Second Commit' >> README.md
```

Comment: This is helpful for most common cases, but the request was considering encrypted (eg. binary, not line orientated content)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tiny script I wrote using `filter-repo` to replace a single file's contents, inspired by [insert-beginning](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/main/contrib/filter-repo-demos/insert-beginning) from the git `filter-repo` contrib scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

SRC_FILE="$1"
TO_REPLACE_PATH="$2"

git filter-repo --commit-callback "for change in commit.file_changes:
    if (change.type != b'D' and change.filename == b'${TO_REPLACE_PATH}'):
        change.blob_id = b'$(git hash-object -w ${SRC_FILE})'"
```

Note that this handles commits, not blobs. It replaces any modification to the file matching the name with a blob created from the new source file.

Also, note that this isn't using `--force` currently (though you may need to add that), as [the filter-repo documentation](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#FRESHCLONE) strongly suggests that you clone any local repositories with `--no-local` instead of using `--force`, which can be risky.

Comment: Works with --force, but needs extra filter-repo. Why does it not handle blobs?

Comment: The blob callback can't do what you want because blobs don't have names (and the same blob might be referenced by multiple names in a tree), this is why the script works on commits. You could have instead matched blobs by ID and modified their data, but this is a bit more straightforward. In any case, if the original blobs aren't referenced anymore, they'll be removed as part of `filter-repo`'s cleanup.